# What is this wrench icon I have in the bottom right corner?

Tags: far-cry-4

I have this icon stuck on my screen in the bottom right corner. What does it mean?

[image: yellow wrench in a circle]

Comment: To add details to Greg's answer: If you go in your crafting menu (in the pause menu) you'll see some items are not darkened like the others, these are the items ready to be upgraded or crafted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that you have collected enough of a particular type of animal skin to craft something.